# Mariadb Galera 10.5.13-16 Node Crash

Tags: mariadb, galera

I have a cluster with 2 galera nodes and 1 arbitrator.
My node 1 crashed I don't understand why..

Here is the log of the node 1.
It seems that it is a problem with the pthread library.

Also every requests are proxied by 2 HAProxy.

```
2023-01-03 12:08:55 0 [Warning] WSREP: Handshake failed: peer did not return a certificate
2023-01-03 12:08:55 0 [Warning] WSREP: Handshake failed: peer did not return a certificate
2023-01-03 12:08:56 0 [Warning] WSREP: Handshake failed: http request
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::wrapexcept<std::system_error>'
  what():  remote_endpoint: Transport endpoint is not connected
230103 12:08:56 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs

We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

Server version: 10.5.13-MariaDB-1:10.5.13+maria~focal
key_buffer_size=134217728
read_buffer_size=2097152
max_used_connections=101
max_threads=102
thread_count=106
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 760333 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0x0 thread_stack 0x49000
mariadbd(my_print_stacktrace+0x32)[0x55b1b67f7e42]
Printing to addr2line failed
mariadbd(handle_fatal_signal+0x485)[0x55b1b62479a5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x153c0)[0x7ff88ea983c0]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0xcb)[0x7ff88e59e18b]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x12b)[0x7ff88e57d859]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0x9e911)[0x7ff88e939911]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0xaa38c)[0x7ff88e94538c]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0xaa3f7)[0x7ff88e9453f7]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0xaa6a9)[0x7ff88e9456a9]
/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so(+0x448ad)[0x7ff884b5e8ad]
/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so(+0x1fc315)[0x7ff884d16315]
/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so(+0x1ff7eb)[0x7ff884d197eb]
/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so(+0x1ffc28)[0x7ff884d19c28]
/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so(+0x2065b6)[0x7ff884d205b6]
/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so(+0x1f81f3)[0x7ff884d121f3]
/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so(+0x1e6f04)[0x7ff884d00f04]
/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so(+0x103438)[0x7ff884c1d438]
/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so(+0xe8eea)[0x7ff884c02eea]
/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so(+0xe9a8d)[0x7ff884c03a8d]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x9609)[0x7ff88ea8c609]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x43)[0x7ff88e67a293]
The manual page at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/how-to-produce-a-full-stack-trace-for-mysqld/ contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
Writing a core file...
Working directory at /var/lib/mysql
Resource Limits:
Fatal signal 11 while backtracing
```

PS: if you want more data ask me :)

Answer (score 1):

OK it seems that 2 simultaneous scans of OpenVAS crashes the node.
I tried with version 10.5.13 and 10.5.16 -> crash.

Solution: Upgrade to 10.5.17 at least.